# OCR Resume Scanning Software

Tags: windows, ocr

Is there a good software option to take physical resumes, at say a job fair, and scan them using OCR technology, which will then enter the scanned and readable resumes into an accompanied resume database? I know of software for purely OCR image processing and nothing else such as Readiris, ABBYY, and Omnipage, but is there a more full form option out there particularly for resume scanning?

Comment: Running on what OS? How much are you willing to pay, if needed?

Comment: Windows. Just curious as to what my options are, will evaluate prices later.

Comment: Where do you come from? Do resumes in your country always look the same? The ones I've seen in Germany (I do interviews and I do interview trainings) are so different that I doubt such a thing is possible.

Comment: Plus, of course, not everyone is using the same database schema

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a commercial product then you should check out the [LEADTOOLS Forms Recognition SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/forms). With this, you will be able to load in a blank image and use that as a template to make fields to be recognized. Once you have a template set up, you will be able to load your filled in files to be read.

There is actually a video that will explain the in depth process of our Master Forms Demo. That video can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DjdzXgcBd0)